# How to prevent the following CSRF attack on Oauth2?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

- The victim authenticates via system browser at the Authorization Server in a Oauth2 authorization code flow and is issued a session cookie by the Authorization Server
- The victim is tricked into clicking at a link on attackers web site which launches an Oauth2 authorization request via victims browser towards the Oauth2 Authorization Server with client ID and redirect URI for the attackers Oauth2 client
- The Authorization Server will not need to authenticate victim since a session cookie is already issued by the Authorization Server but just ask victim to grant the attackers client access – which in this case the victim is assumed to do
- The Authorization Server will redirect victims browser to the attackers redirect URI (which is assumed to point to a web application) with authorization response with Authorization Code for victim
- The attacker is now in possession of Authorization Code for the victim, that he or she can exchange for refresh & access token

What are the best possible precautions against this except for the victim not to accept to grant the attackers client access?
I mean the average internet user will typically click accept to a lot of stuff on a normal day without thinking much about it.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that there is an [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I think application security, as being a multi-disciplinary area between security and coding, probably belongs more to StackOverflow. Information Security as discussed on Information Security Stack Exchange is a much broader area, and a lot of people are not developers. They deal with issues on a different level, and sometimes more from a theoretical standpoint. So in short I think this is indeed a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, the attacker would have to register his client with the authentication provider, which in an enterprise setting should not be possible. Also as the redirect URI is not registered, the AP should never redirect the user back to the attacker.

In case of public APs where anyone can register a client, this is indeed a problem, but this is also the point in a sense. If the user authorizes the attacker's app, then the attacker's app will have access. As it is not different from normal apps in this regard, users will have to take care (while you are right, the majority of users will just click OK to anything).

The AP could still maintain a blacklist based on user reports for example, but that is a weak control. The best an AP can probably do is provide adequate information and warnings for the user, delaying the OK button for a few seconds to try to get them to read, etc.